# Android onPostExecute not been recognize

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rest, oop

This is my code:

```
//.___ Async task bring info from API __./
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        mMovieDto = mDataSource.getPopularMovies();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        fillList();
    }
};
asyncTask.execute();
```

I'm getting the error that the `onPostExecute` is not overriding from super, witch is the right way to add this king of method to my `AsyncTask`?

Thanks for the help
Jose

Comment: Show the parameters in the AsyncTask definition.  As it is now, your onPostExecute() needs to take an Object parameter, since that's what doInBackground() returns.

Comment: Worked! Please post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you want it to return a Long result onPostExecute then change you AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() to AsyncTask<Void,Void,Long> asyncTask = new AsyncTask();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the AsyncTask's generic types:

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> 1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> 2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
> 3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
>
> Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:
>
> `private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }`

Change your code like this:

```
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mMovieDto = mDataSource.getPopularMovies();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        fillList();
    }
};
asyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: Shouldn't he change it to be `AsyncTask<Object[],Void,Long>` ?  That would match the parameters the OP was going for in his question.

Comment: it seems to me that he didn't use any params, nor result in his sample code. They are useless, i think the best solution is to use `Void`.